# ¿Cómo insertar caractéres especiales en cadenas en MySQL con PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla que almacena nombre, que pueden llevar `'`, `"`.

Si lleva comilla simple `'` por ejemplo, el dato es `PEPE'S` cambio en el insert la comilla simple que encierra los campos con la comilla doble:

```
foreach($_DATOS_EXCEL as $campo => $valor){
                        $sql = "INSERT INTO excel  (nombres,apellidos,genero,carrera,edad,email,activo)  VALUES ('";
                        foreach ($valor as $campo2 => $valor2){
                            $campo2 == "activo" ? $sql.= $valor2."');" : $sql.= $valor2."','";
                        }
```

Pero puede ser que el dato del campo nombre sea `JOSE EL "PEPE"`

En el caso de que puedan llevar tanto la simple, com la doble incluidos en el valor, ¿cómo puedo simplificar esto?

Gracias,

Comment: Utiliza sentencias preparadas y evitarás la inyección SQL. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%c3%b3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%c3%b3n-sql-en-php?r=SearchResults

Comment: Hola @Javi fer2, el tema es que no estoy intentando evitar sql injection, sino que hay valores en el excel que leo y del que hago el insert que llevan el texto entre dobles ". Cambié primero la comilla simple por la doble en el comienzo de values y en cada valor para que me cogiera nombre de calles con comila simple y ahí bien, pero si además viene un valor con dobles comillas, ya no se como tengo que escribrlo, pues he probado poner varios pares de comillas y nada

Comment: @oraculo Independientemente de que quieras o no evitar la inyección SQL (idealmente la seguridad debería tener prioridad), las sentencias preparadas que menciona Xerif ayudarán con el problema de las comillas y además evitarán vulnerabilidades de inyección SQL. Son una doble victoria.

Comment: @oraculo Tu problema es de inyección seas consciente o no, el uso de sentencias preparadas hace irrelevante los caracteres que contengan tus valores, por lo que prodras insertar comillas sin ningún problema.

Comment: Gracias todos por la ayuda. Me iré pegando con el tema de inyección SQL. De momento, he encontrado algo que me ha servido, pero me dá algún problemilla de tiempos, porl oque lo abriré en consulta nueva.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero crea um patrón para las comillas cambiando dobles para simples.
Segun antes de insertar anãde una comilla doble para cada comilla simple por ej: "'"(" ' ").

Cada caso tendra una manera de hacer.
Sigue el exemplo del nombre [ Juan EL "PEPE'S"].

```
$fnombre=$_POST['fnombre'];
$fnombre = str_replace('"',"|",$fnombre); // primer cambio, comilla doble para "|"
$fnombre = str_replace("'","''",$fnombre); // segun cambio, comilla simple para "''"
$fnombre = str_replace("|",'"',$fnombre); // ultimo cambio, | para comilla doble
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi tabla está con Charset latin1 y collation latin1_swedisch_ci

Comment: Hola @Jose Bonfim, estoy intentando lo que me dices pero algo estoy haciendo mal que no me funciona. He probado esto para quitar las comillas simples estoy usando por ejemplo, al comienzo del insert para VALUES, en vez de ('"; uso (\""; y en cada valor cambio la ' tambien por "\",\""; y me lo monta bien, pero si hay un valor que va encerrado entre " me falla

Comment: O sea, si yo hago el insert a mano para el valor Piso finca "1234" de la siguiente forma 
`"Piso ""finca"" 14948"`
funciona, pero no se como hacerlo en el sql de php, pues parte central de la cadena la que va entrte dobles comillas

Comment: ¡Gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 1):

Hay varias formas de hacerlo en realidad.

SQL por defecto puede escapar las comillas haciendo uso del backslahs o barra invertida (\), si haces eso: INSERT INTO Editorial ('editorial') VALUES ('O\'Reilly'), automáticamente lo escapará y lo insertará.

Con php y usando mysqli, debes usar la función real_scape_string() para hacerlo o en su defecto con mysqli_real_scape_string, y pasándole la variable de conexión y tu string a escapar, añadirá ese registro.

Como te dijeron antes, es mejor usar PDO. PDO puede realizar esto de dos maneras:

1- A través de sentencias preparadas: `

```
try{
     $objetoPDO = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Test, 'root', 'root');
}catch (PDOException $e) {
      echo "¡Error!: " . $e->getMessage();
      die();
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE nickname LIKE :nombre;";
$pdoStat = $objetoPDO->prepare($query);
$pdoStat->bindValue(':nombre', "l'asdas'", PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

` o

2- Usando el método quote de PDO:

```
$objetoPDO = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Test, 'root', 'root');

$nombre = $objetoPDO->quote($_GET['nombre']);

$query = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE nickname LIKE $nombre";

$pdoStat = $objetoPDO->prepare($query);

$result = $pdoStat->execute();
```

Comment: ¡Gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

El excel que leo y del cual inserto los datos, tiene 55 columnas igual que la tabla MySql. Al final, para poder acelerar, he estado probando entrelo que me habéis dicho y buscando más cosas y probando y probando, y esto me ha funcionado, tanto para subir el excel, leerlo, insertar sin problemas de caractéres. Lo pongo como respuesta, pero si alguien pudiera decirme como mejorar el tiempo de ejecución de este "ladrillo" lo agradezco, pues cuando lleva 2.000 filas insertadas de las 7.000 del excel, me da un 504 el nginx. Aquí el ladrillo:

```
<?php
include('dbconect.php');
require_once('vendor/php-excel-reader/excel_reader2.php');
require_once('vendor/SpreadsheetReader.php');

if (isset($_POST["import"]))
{
    
$allowedFileType = ['application/vnd.ms-excel','text/xls','text/xlsx','application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'];
  
  if(in_array($_FILES["file"]["type"],$allowedFileType)){

        $targetPath = 'subidas/'.$_FILES['file']['name'];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $targetPath);
        
        $Reader = new SpreadsheetReader($targetPath);
        
        $sheetCount = count($Reader->sheets());
        for($i=0;$i<$sheetCount;$i++)
        {
            
            $Reader->ChangeSheet($i);
            
            foreach ($Reader as $Row)
            {
          
                $c1 = "";
                if(isset($Row[0])) {
                    $c1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[0]);
                }
                
                $c2 = "";
                if(isset($Row[1])) {
                    $c2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[1]);
                }
                
                $c3 = "";
                if(isset($Row[2])) {
                    $c3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[2]);
                }
                
                $c4 = "";
                if(isset($Row[3])) {
                    $c4 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[3]);
                }
                 $c5 = "";
                if(isset($Row[4])) {
                    $c5 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[4]);
                }
                 $c6 = "";
                if(isset($Row[5])) {
                    $c6 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[5]);
                }
                 $c7 = "";
                if(isset($Row[6])) {
                    $c7 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[6]);
                }
                 $c8 = "";
                if(isset($Row[7])) {
                    $c8 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[7]);
                }
                 $c9 = "";
                if(isset($Row[8])) {
                    $c9 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[8]);
                }
                 $c10 = "";
                if(isset($Row[9])) {
                    $c10 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[9]);
                }
                 $c11 = "";
                if(isset($Row[10])) {
                    $c11 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[10]);
                }
                 $c12 = "";
                if(isset($Row[11])) {
                    $c12 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[11]);
                }
                 $c13 = "";
                if(isset($Row[12])) {
                    $c13 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[12]);
                }
                 $c14 = "";
                if(isset($Row[13])) {
                    $c14 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[13]);
                }
                 $c15 = "";
                if(isset($Row[14])) {
                    $c15 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[14]);
                }
                 $c16 = "";
                if(isset($Row[15])) {
                    $c16 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[15]);
                }
                
                $c17 = "";
                if(isset($Row[16])) {
                    $c17 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[16]);
                }
                 $c18 = "";
                if(isset($Row[17])) {
                    $c18 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[17]);
                }
                 $c19 = "";
                if(isset($Row[18])) {
                    $c19 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[18]);
                }
                 $c20 = "";
                if(isset($Row[19])) {
                    $c20 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[19]);
                }
                 $c21 = "";
                if(isset($Row[20])) {
                    $c21 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[20]);
                }
                 $c22 = "";
                if(isset($Row[21])) {
                    $c22 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[21]);
                }
                 $c23 = "";
                if(isset($Row[22])) {
                    $c23 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[22]);
                }
                 $c24 = "";
                if(isset($Row[23])) {
                    $c24 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[23]);
                }
                $c25 = "";
                if(isset($Row[24])) {
                    $c25 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[24]);
                }
                 $c26 = "";
                if(isset($Row[25])) {
                    $c26 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[25]);
                }
                 $c27 = "";
                if(isset($Row[26])) {
                    $c27 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[26]);
                }
                $c28 = "";
                if(isset($Row[27])) {
                    $c28 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[27]);
                }
                $c29 = "";
                if(isset($Row[28])) {
                    $c29 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[28]);
                }
                 $c30 = "";
                if(isset($Row[29])) {
                    $c30 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[29]);
                }
                 $c31 = "";
                if(isset($Row[30])) {
                    $c31 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[30]);
                }
                $c32 = "";
                if(isset($Row[31])) {
                    $c32 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[31]);
                }
                $c33 = "";
                if(isset($Row[32])) {
                    $c33 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[32]);
                }
                 $c34 = "";
                if(isset($Row[33])) {
                    $c34 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[33]);
                }
                 $c35 = "";
                if(isset($Row[34])) {
                    $c35 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[34]);
                }
                 $c36 = "";
                if(isset($Row[35])) {
                    $c36 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[35]);
                }
                 $c37 = "";
                if(isset($Row[36])) {
                    $c37 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[36]);
                }
                 $c38 = "";
                if(isset($Row[37])) {
                    $c38 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[37]);
                }
                 $c39 = "";
                if(isset($Row[38])) {
                    $c39 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[38]);
                }
                 $c40 = "";
                if(isset($Row[39])) {
                    $c40 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[39]);
                }
                $c41 = "";
                if(isset($Row[40])) {
                    $c41 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[40]);
                }
                 $c42 = "";
                if(isset($Row[41])) {
                    $c42 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[41]);
                }
                 $c43 = "";
                if(isset($Row[42])) {
                    $c43 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[42]);
                }
                 $c44 = "";
                if(isset($Row[43])) {
                    $c44 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[43]);
                }
                 $c45 = "";
                if(isset($Row[44])) {
                    $c45 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[44]);
                }
                 $c46 = "";
                if(isset($Row[45])) {
                    $c46 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[45]);
                }
                 $c47 = "";
                if(isset($Row[46])) {
                    $c47 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[46]);
                }
                 $c48 = "";
                if(isset($Row[47])) {
                    $c48 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[47]);
                }
                 $c49 = "";
                if(isset($Row[48])) {
                    $c49 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[48]);
                }
                 $c50 = "";
                if(isset($Row[49])) {
                    $c50 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[49]);
                }
                 $c51 = "";
                if(isset($Row[50])) {
                    $c51 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[50]);
                }
                 $c52 = "";
                if(isset($Row[51])) {
                    $c52 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[51]);
                }
                 $c53 = "";
                if(isset($Row[52])) {
                    $c53 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[52]);
                }
                 $c54 = "";
                if(isset($Row[53])) {
                    $c54 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[53]);
                }
                 $c55 = "";
                if(isset($Row[54])) {
                    $c55 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[54]);
                }
                
                
                if (!empty($c1) || !empty($c2) || !empty($c3) || !empty($c4) || !empty($c5) || !empty($c6) || !empty($c7) || !empty($c8) || !empty($c9)
                  || !empty($c10) || !empty($c11) || !empty($c12) || !empty($c13) || !empty($c14) || !empty($c15) || !empty($c16)
                  || !empty($c17) || !empty($c18) || !empty($c19) || !empty($c20) || !empty($c21) || !empty($c22) || !empty($c23)
                  || !empty($c24) || !empty($c25) || !empty($c26) || !empty($c27) || !empty($c28) || !empty($c29) || !empty($c30) || !empty($c31)
                   || !empty($c32) || !empty($c33) || !empty($c34) || !empty($c35) || !empty($c36) || !empty($c37) || !empty($c38) || !empty($c39) || !empty($c40)
                    || !empty($c41) || !empty($c42) || !empty($c43) || !empty($c44) || !empty($c45) || !empty($c46) || !empty($c47) || !empty($c48) || !empty($c49) || !empty($c50)
                     || !empty($c51) || !empty($c52) || !empty($c53) || !empty($c54) || !empty($c55)
                     
                     ) {
                   
                    $query = "INSERT INTO tabla_c50(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10,c11,c12,c13,c14,c15,c16,c17,c18,c19,c20,c21,c22,c23,c24,c25,c26,c27,c28,c29,c30,
                    c31,c32,c33,c34,c35,c36,c37,c38,c39,c40,c41,c42,c43,c44,c45,c46,c47,c48,c49,c50.c51.c52,c53,c54,c55)
                        
                        values('".$c1."','".$c2."','".$c3."','".$c4."','".$c5."','".$c6."','".$c7."','".$c8."','".$c9."'
                        ,'".$c10."','".$c11."','".$c12."','".$c13."','".$c14."','".$c15."','".$c16."'
                        ,'".$c17."','".$c18."','".$c19."','".$c20."','".$c21."','".$c22."','".$c23."','".$c24."','".$c25."','".$c26."'
                        ,'".$c27."','".$c28."','".$c29."','".$c30."','".$c31."'
                        ,'".$c32."','".$c33."','".$c34."','".$c35."','".$c36."','".$c37."','".$c38."','".$c39."','".$c40."'
                        ,'".$c41."','".$c42."','".$c43."','".$c44."','".$c45."','".$c46."','".$c47."','".$c48."','".$c49."'
                        ,'".$c50."','".$c51."','".$c52."','".$c53."','".$c54."','".$c55."')";
                        
                        
                        
                    $resultados = mysqli_query($con, $query);
                    
                    if (! empty($resultados)) {
                        $type = "success";
                        $message = "Excel importado correctamente";
                    } else {
                        $type = "error";
                        $message = "Hubo un problema al importar registros";
                    }
                }
             }
        
         }
  }
  else
  { 
        $type = "error";
        $message = "El archivo enviado es invalido. Por favor vuelva a intentarlo";
  }
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
<title></title>


<link href="dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="assets/sticky-footer-navbar.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="assets/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
<header> 
  
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark"> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Importar Datos</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"> <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active"> <a class="nav-link" href="index.php">Importar<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a> </li>
      </ul>
      
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>

<div class="container">
  <h3 class="mt-5">Importar archivo Excel</h3>
  <hr>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-12"> 
      <!-- Contenido -->
    
    <div class="outer-container">
        <form action="" method="post"
            name="frmExcelImport" id="frmExcelImport" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div>
                <label>Seleccionar Archivo Excel</label> <input type="file" name="file"
                    id="file" accept=".xls,.xlsx">
                <button type="submit" id="submit" name="import"
                    class="btn-submit">Importar Registros</button>
        
            </div>
        
        </form>
        
    </div>
    <div id="response" class="<?php if(!empty($type)) { echo $type . " display-block"; } ?>"><?php if(!empty($message)) { echo $message; } ?></div>
        <!-- Fin Contenido --> 
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container"> <span class="text-muted">
    <p> 2021</p>
    </span> </div>
</footer>
<script src="assets/jquery-1.12.4-jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Aparte de poder optimizar o que no se corte cuando lleva 2000 filas insertadas, ¿cómo podría poner un loading o algo similar mietras se ejecuta el proceso?